# Vous savez comment ce n'est pas toujours simple de se trouver

Tags: conjonctions, adverbe-interrogatif

*Pas moins de 123 nouveau logements étudiants à louer dès maintenant* dans *24 heures*.

> Si vous êtes un étudiant montréalais, vous savez **comment** ce n'est pas
> toujours simple de se trouver un logement abordable à Montréal dans le
> marche actuel.

J'écrirais *vous savez **que** ce n'est pas toujours simple*. Est-ce que *comment* souligne avec emphase la difficulté de trouver un logement dans cette phrase ?

Comment: "Une lettre ouverte sera envoyée sous peu à Emmanuel Macron, ajoute-t-il. On voit mal comment on peut faire de la coiffure sans diplôme. On est prêts à inviter le ministre à passer une journée dans une entreprise et voir **comment ce n'est pas simple de coiffer**". https://lentreprise.lexpress.fr/gestion-fiscalite/les-coiffeurs-en-guerre-contre-la-loi-macron-2_1740771.html

Answer (score 1):

L'adverbe ***que*** serait neutre ici alors que ***comment*** indique la manière avec laquelle on a de la difficulté à trouver un logement abordable.

On trouvera plus souvent ***comme*** (habituel) voire ***combien*** (soutenu) ici qui souligneraient l'intensité, la quantité (de difficulté).

> vous savez **comme** ce n'est pas toujours simple […]
> vous savez **combien** c'est parfois compliqué […]

On entend parfois aussi, dans un registre parlé très relâché, le fustigé ***comment que*** :

> Vous savez **comment que** c'est pas toujours simple […]